# How to manipulate an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

```
<body>
    $product
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var product = '$product';
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
     var k = product[i]
     alert(k)
    }
</script>
```

The array comes from a python script.

The $product has value `['a','b','c']`.

When I want to get the value from $product, it returns error: **global name 'i' is not defined**

If I replace the `$product[i]` with `$product[0]` or `$product[1]`, it works.

Comment: this looks like you are trying to mix php and jsvascript .... they don't run in same environment

Comment: @charlietfl The $product value is from my python code.If I delete the quotes around the $product[i],it will be a string without quotes.Such as 'var k = a',cause an error 'a is not defined'

Comment: I don't have any experience with trying to use python with JS, but I'd assume the python would only be server side which is where your problem is. It most likely needs written to a JS variable and then you will use the new JS array to handle the for loop.

Comment: it's not about deleting quotes... it's about presenting raw javascript with server code in it that doesn't appear to be contained in any type of print statement

Comment: you must understand that first the python code run, server side, trying to access an i variable that doesn't exist. If it worked it would produce the javascript code that would be sent to the browser: there the javascript code would be executed

Comment: @cruelcage Basically, your problem is this: python is at the bus stop at 1PM. JS is there at 3PM, but python has long since left. Now if python left a note for JS at 1PM, it would still be there at 3PM and JS could pick it up. But there is no way for them to meet face to face at the bus stop.

Comment: do this....   open the javascript output in browser , or source view of browser and see what's there.... if it's the string `'$product[i]'` you ren't passing server variables to client properly

Comment: @charlietfl You're right.I pass the wrong variables.But it can display in the html tags with <h1>$product[0]</h1>.I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: "The $product value is from my python code". To help, I would need a **much** more thorough explanation of what this *actually means to you*. Where is "my python code"? What exactly does it do? Where is this javascript code? What does the javascript code look like when you actually load the page - does it still say `$product`? How **exactly** are you expecting the **string** consisting of a dollar sign, the word "product", an open square bracket, the letter 'i', and a close square bracket to get replaced?

Comment: output the python the same way you write out to a page using whatever print methods you usually use, and convert it to JSON within that output

Comment: Okay, so you are also attempting to show the array in the page body. Does that part work? Again, *what does the javascript code look like when you actually load the page*? Call it up in your web browser and view the source. You tagged this as a python question; why aren't you showing us the python code?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel $product works in the page body,but will convert from string to HTML entities in the JavaScript code.Such as from  ['a','b','c'] to [&#39;a&#39;, &#39;b&#39;, &#39;c&#39;].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1.print array values into Javascript, then loop the array in Javascript

You have to prepare python equivalent to implode PHP function and quote wrapper to output values as a string.

```
var product = ['$product_values'];
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var k = product[i]
    alert(k)
}
```

2.loop array in Python and print your output into Javascript

Comment: Come on. Try to evaluate it to proper syntax. It should be: `var product = ['a','b','c'];` and at first you wrap it with quotes. Saying "quote wrapper" I meant wrapping each of values from array, not the array.

Comment: After I delete the quotes,the source code in the browser:"var product = [&#39;a&#39;, &#39;b&#39;, &#39;c&#39;];"You can have a look with my url.

Comment: I think you don't get the slightest idea of what should be printed into the $product_values variable.

Comment: $product works in the page body,but will convert from string to HTML entities in the JavaScript code.Such as from ['a','b','c'] to [&#39;a&#39;, &#39;b&#39;, &#39;c&#39;].

Comment: I solve it with (convertStr = $('<div />').html("$product").text(); arr = JSON.parse(convertStr);) Thanks so much!!But why the $product is an array in the html body while is a string in the JavaScript?It works after I conver it to an array.

Comment: I think $product has never acted like array and you only printed it to HTML

Comment: It acts as an array when it is in the html body.I can print $product[0] or $product[1] or $product[2] in the html body.

Comment: Yes, because you use index within Python. You print value, not array element. That's the difference. You can't print array itself because Javascript can only react to string which declares a new array.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept the best answer to remove question from 'unanswered' ones.